# Can hard-drive benchmark apps damage your hard-drive?

Tags: hard-drive, benchmark

I want to measure the read/write speed of my hard-drive.
I came accross [this page](http://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/test-mac-hard-disk-read-write-speeds-with-blackmagic-disk-speed-test/) recommending Blackmagic Disk Speed Test.

There is a frame saying this:

> Note: Blackmagic Disk Speed Test puts hard drive under extreme stress during data write and read operations, therefore it’s recommended to save your work before conducting the tests.

Now my question is: Could that 'extreme stress' on my hard-drive damage my hard-drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disk benchmarks perform many read/write operations to measure the performance of your disk. It is recommend to save any work as high amount of those operations **may** cause some applications to slow down and crash by being unable to load/save data from/to your disk.

> Can benchmark app damage your disk?

No, however if your HDD or SSD has been extensively used over its lifetime then it is likely that its health status has decreased, making it more likely to fail. Keep in mind that it would be nothing but a coincidence if it would fail during the benchmark.